# Linq to Sql Left join ang get average value

Tags: linq

Let's say i have an Linq query :

```
var query = from course in _unitOfWork.Course.GetAll() 
            join candidate in _unitOfWork.CandidateCourses.GetAll() on course.Id equals candidate.Course_id join cr in _unitOfWork.CourseReviews.GetAll() on course.Id equals cr.Course_id into g from rt in g.DefaultIfEmpty() 
            where candidate.UserId == CandidateId 
            select new CourseFields { Id = course.Id, 
                                      Course_name = course.Course_name, 
                                      Course_description = course.Course_description,
                                      Rating = g.Average(x => x.Rating), 
                                      TotalSections = sections.Count(), };
```

Here i am getting exception in calculating Average of Rating, When there is no data in table for that particular course.

Can someone help where i am doing wrong?

Comment: So, what would you like that the rating will be if there are no records?

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework? Not that it would change that error, but there's a more elegant way of writing this with lambda notation.

Answer (score 0):

`Average` requires at list one element in the sequence.

You can add a `DefaultIfEmpty` to set the default rating if no elements exists.

```
...
Rating = g.DefaultIfEmpty(0).Average(x => x.Rating),
...
```

If you had rating as a `Nullable` type (like `Nullable<double>>`)
then it would not throw an exception but retrun `null` instead

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this one out. Check for null before doing an average
...

```
Rating = (g!=null && g.Count()>0)?g.Average(x => x.Rating):0,
```

...